# Render subview in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

Please refer the picture and here under is explanation what I want to do

[image]

I'm using bacbone.js with modular approch using require.js

1. My index.html contains only

   ```
     <body class="claro">
        <div id='container'>
       </div>
     </body>
   ```
2. Main view and header view are two different modules and load first time
   For this I have created one class Viewmanager that is called on page load

   ```
   // This is the main container of 
   el: $('#container')


   mv = new MainView();
   this.$el.append(mv.render().el);


   header = new HeaderView();
   this.$el.append(header.render(mv).el);
   ```
3. Now on HeaderView i have three links and want to render different views respectively on their click but please note main view and header view will remain always there. I wonder how to do it.

Please note I have different templates for different views stored in there indiviual .html files

Comment: Using [Backbone Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) might save you some trouble with its Region and RegionManager that (I think) are doing exactly this.

Comment: [this backbone tutorial with code](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/) demostrates how to do what you want. Download the source and inside router.js you'll see how you render footer/header only once